# iOS Webview Echo issue When Muting/Unmuting

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, webrtc

I have a WebRTC implementation that is inside a Webview on iOS 15. I am enabling the audio/disabling the audio as such:

```
mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
setTimeout(() => {                              mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
}, 1500);
```

And same for the video tracks as well:

```
mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
setTimeout(() => {                              mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
}, 1500);
```

Anytime I enable and disable a track (audio or video), when the track is re-enabled, there is an echo. The code works fine on everything else (Android, Safari, Chrome, etc) but only has this behavior with WebRTC on iOS 15 inside a webview.

Anyone else come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

The update was fixed when I updated my iPhone to 15.6. Apparently there are quite a view WEBTRC issues between iOS 15.1 to 15.5.